# How optimized are writes to /dev/null in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

In a Linux userland program, if I `open(2)` `/dev/null` (or do something equivalent, like redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null`), and then `write(2)` to the resulting handle, how deep into the kernel does my request to write get propagated before being discarded? Does a memory copy of the data happen? Does a kernel context switch happen?

If I use `writev(2)` against the `/dev/null` handle instead, is the kernel smart enough to skip walking the passed iovec?

Comment: Every system call causes a kernel context switch -- you have to get to the device driver to do anything device-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since null is a char device, a write passes a pointer to the data and a size. write just returns the count passed in, no data copy occurs.  See: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L453